# one column as a substring of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, as table-a, table-b and table-c. I have stuck with a problem where I have substring, say XYZ, present in column-1 of table-a, whereas in table-b i have some rows with XYZ as a substring in one of the column. I want to fetch all those rows from both of the tables, table-a as well as table-b, where I have one of the column from table-c='123'(e.g)

Below is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.column-1, b.column-2 
FROM table-a a, table-b b, table-c c 
WHERE c.column='123' AND a.column-1=b.column-2;
```

With this query it is printing rows from table-b where only XYZ present but not %XYZ%.

Thanks in advance for co-operation..

Comment: Apparently none of the rows in table B that contain '%XYZ%' have a column-2 that matches a value in a.column-1. You say `'that have one of the column from table C'`, but your query shows no correlation between C and the other tables whatsover. You basically have a cross join now. Please provide us with details about their relations. Actual table structure with real names, and maybe even an SQLFiddle would help.

Answer (score 5):

I think the condition you're looking for is something like:

```
AND b.column-2 LIKE CONCAT('%', a.column-1, '%')
```